# Bash not understanding super easy if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm a bash newcomer and just started doing some simple scripts this evening. This one is a super easy task from HackerRank, but I can't get the idea why don't my solutions work and believe me, I've tried many. Input is just one letter, either 'y', 'Y', 'n' or 'N' and the output should be 'YES' for 'y' and 'Y' and 'NO' for 'N' and 'n'. My solution is here:

```
read letter

if (($letter == "y"))
then
    echo "YES"
elif (($letter == "Y"))
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

but still the output is always 'YES', even for random letter like 'G' or anything. I have no idea how does this freaknig bash work, please someone explain it to me!

Comment: If you've tried many, then you haven't tried `if [[ $letter == "y" ]]`.

Comment: Isnt the syntax if [ $letter == "y" ]?

Comment: That's right and I didn't actually know that spaces inside the brackets are obligatory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`((...))` is for arithmetic. For string comparisons, use `[[ ... ]]`, `[ ... ]`, or `test`. (Mind the spaces inside the brackets. They are not optional.)

```
if [[ $letter == "y" ]]
then
    echo "YES"
elif [[ $letter == "Y" ]]
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

You could also do this with a `case` block.

```
case $letter in
    [yY]) echo "YES";;
    *)    echo "NO";;
esac
```

Comment: So... spaces that was, thanks a lot for saying that!

Comment: Or `if [[ $letter =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi`

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect.

You should be doing:

```
if [ "$letter" == "y" ] # for posix compliance, use = instead of ==
   #do stuff
fi
```

Comment: -1. Single-bracket conditionals are old POSIX syntax, and there is no reason to use it if you can guarantee that the script will be interpreted by Bash.

Comment: Seeing how the question is tagged `bash`, I think it is wise to assume `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the beginning of each script.

Comment: If you use single brackets, you should use a single equal sign for string comparison, not double equals, just to be sh-compatible.

Comment: Thanks for help, I just didn't know about spaces inside the brackets

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar When there is a choice, many prefer portable syntax: you never know when someone will try to run your script under `dash` or `ash`.  Also, `[[` has some quirks to it.  mjs, when using `[`, you should put `$letter` in double-quotes.  Without them, an empty `$letter`  causes an error.  Also, `=` rather than `==`.

Comment: Missing the spaces inside the brackets is a very common mistake, as is putting spaces around `=` in an assignment `a = 1` compared to `a=1`. sh-syntax is a bit weird in this regard :-)

Comment: @John1024 Many thanks. Agree on the portable syntax.

Comment: According to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html "==" is valid and a synonym for "="

Comment: @mjs `==` is a synonym for `=` under `bash` but it is [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and it will fail, for example, under `dash`.   (Your answer already has my +1.)